How to fix "Could not complete vectorization action. The service failed to authenticate to the vectorization endpoint." in Azure AI Search?
I created a search index in Azure AI Search. When trying to do a search via the Azure AI Search web UI, I get:

"Could not complete vectorization action. The service failed to authenticate to the vectorization endpoint."

How to fix it?

